# How to backup printers driver?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-8, printer, network-printer

As a network administrator I sometimes have to do a clean windows install on a system and I want to know if there is a way to backup up printers driver that were installed in on old version of windows (some of them are network printers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you need is [Microsoft Print Migrator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30935).

> You can export print queues, printer settings, printer ports, and
>   language monitors, and then import them on another print server
>   running a Windows operating system. This is an efficient way to
>   consolidate multiple print servers or replace an older print server.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722360.aspx)

note: I have used this tool in the past and found it effective.

Answer (score -2):

You can [do it](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/back-up-your-files) from Windows 7 and above. 
Pro/Ultimate versions will install drivers automatically using **[Windows Update](http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com)**.